# How to solve a tiktok captcha with 2captcha?

Tags: captcha, tiktok

Does anybody know how to solve the tiktok captcha with the 2captcha api or any other method, yet I don't think that another method will work, but I am open to proposition.

Their documentation is not really clear. In the tiktok section https://2captcha.com/2captcha-api#solving_tiktok. I do not understand the part where it says "Find a values for aid and host parameters. ". And even when I try to type their code `` renderCaptcha = ({aid, host}) => console.log(`aid: ${aid}, host: ${host}`) `` in the console on tiktok.com there are no real values that are found. It returns `` ({aid, host}) => console.log(`aid: ${aid}, host: ${host}`) ``.

Also I do not understand what these `aid, host` values are. I have never heard about them.

And their documentation and their github does not contain a section for an actual node.js/javascript implementation of the tiktok captcha solver.

Anyone have some idea about this how to solve the tiktok captchas in node.js puppeteer? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following values for AID and HOST

aid: 1459,
host: 'https://www-useast1a.tiktok.com/'

These are the values for setting up the WebSocket connection with the 2captcha API's.

This was provided by the 2captcha team. But the 2captcha solver doesn't work for TikTok's Captcha setup and returns an "Error_Solving_Captcha".